# How to make text red and then black again?

Tags: vba, ms-word

```vb
Sub MakeTextRed()
'
' MakeTextRed Macro
'
'
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "+Body"
        .Size = 16
        .Bold = False
        .Italic = False
        .Underline = wdUnderlineNone
        .UnderlineColor = wdColorAutomatic
        .StrikeThrough = False
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = False
        .Outline = False
        .Emboss = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Hidden = False
        .SmallCaps = False
        .AllCaps = False
        .Color = wdColorRed
        .Engrave = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .Spacing = 0
        .Scaling = 100
        .Position = 0
        .Kerning = 0
        .Animation = wdAnimationNone
        .SizeBi = 16
        .NameBi = "+Body CS"
        .BoldBi = False
        .ItalicBi = False
        .Ligatures = wdLigaturesNone
        .NumberSpacing = wdNumberSpacingDefault
        .NumberForm = wdNumberFormDefault
        .StylisticSet = wdStylisticSetDefault
        .ContextualAlternates = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Shortcut key is Shift+Alt+R
I want to make it first make text red and then if I press same shortcut again make the text black.

I do not have knowledge of VBA. Please provide logic or algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub toggleColor()
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = -wdColorRed * (.Color <> wdColorRed)
    End With
End Sub
```

If color is not red then `(.Color <> wdColorRed)` = -1 (True as integer) and result = wdColorRed. Otherwise `(.Color <> wdColorRed)` = 0 (False as integer) and result = 0 (wdColorBlack)

Answer (score 3):

```
With Selection.Font
    If .Color = wdColorRed then
        .Color = wdColorBlack
    else
        .Color = wdColorRed
    end if
End With
```

Comment: Will this handle wdColorAutomatic?

Comment: That is not a relevant consideration given the code used.